# ReportViewer não abre no IIS de dev

Tags: iis, reportviewer, visual-studio-2019

Estou com problema no uso do ReportViewer, o mesmo funciona perfeitamente em dev, mas não abre pelo IIS.

detalhes:
Uso no VS2019 corretamente, mas ao efetuar o "publish" e rodar o pacote pelo IIS da minha máquina (teste local), o relatorio exige erro .

Quando faço o build do código e copio os arquivos gerados para o outro servidor remoto de HML , o relatorio roda OK... mas não roda se publicamos o pacote gerado pelo "publish" do VS.

MENSAGEM DE ERRO

Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/APPlocal'.

A definição deste relatório é inválida ou não tem suporte nesta versão do Reporting Services. A definição do relatório pode ter sido criada com uma versão mais recente do Reporting Services, ou inclui conteúdo malformado ou inválido baseado em esquemas do Reporting Services. Detalhes: Dados no nível raiz inválidos.

Linha 1, posição 1.
Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.

Detalhes da Exceção: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: A definição deste relatório é inválida ou não tem suporte nesta versão do Reporting Services. A definição do relatório pode ter sido criada com uma versão mais recente do Reporting Services, ou inclui conteúdo malformado ou inválido baseado em esquemas do Reporting Services. Detalhes: Dados no nível raiz inválidos. Linha 1, posição 1.